# Html5 datalist issue with input text and textarea

Tags: html

I create a data list attached to input it works very well
when i add a text area and i try to write something it shows me suggestions 
this is my html code:

```
<input list="data" type="text">
<datalist id="data">
<option>op1</option>
<option>op2</option>
</datalist>
<textarea></textarea>
```

it works fine in Firefox but not in chrome
Thanks for your help

Comment: w3c says:"The datalist element represents a set of option elements that represent predefined options for other controls."
You need the `list` attribute on such a control to associate the `datalist` element with the control element. `list` **value** = `datalist` **id**. Like you did for the `input`. The Problem is the `list` attribute is not listed as a permitted attribute in the w3c specification for the `textarea` element. From my point of view, if you get any suggestions in the `textarea` with your code in any browser, it is possibly a wrong implementation (bug) of the browser vendor.